# Count the number of Occurrences of each integer from user input using a single dimension array

Tags: java, arrays, integer, variable-assignment, counting

I have to count how many times each number appears in an array.

I have to have a specific out put which i have.  Everything I have works correctly but I need the first loop at the "break" to end without having to press 0.  how can I get it to do this?

Here is a copy of the code:

```
package u07a1_numofoccurrinsevenints;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class U07A1_NumOfOccurrInSevenInts {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number[] = new int [10000000];
    int count[] = new int [10000000];
    int temp = 0;

    System.out.print("Enter seven numbers: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
        number [i] = input.nextInt();
        if (number [i] == 0)
            break;
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
        temp = number [i];
        count [temp]++;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < count.length; i++) {
        if (count [i] > 0 && count [i] == 1) {
            System.out.printf("Number %d occurs %d time\n", i, count [i]);
        }

        else if(count [i] >= 2){
            System.out.printf("Number %d occurs %d times\n", i, count [i]);
        }
    }
}

}
```

and here is a copy of the output:

```
run:
Enter seven numbers: 12 23 44 22 23 22 55
0
Number 12 occurs 1 time
Number 22 occurs 2 times
Number 23 occurs 2 times
Number 44 occurs 1 time
Number 55 occurs 1 time
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 19 seconds)
```

As you can see I have to enter zero to get the first loop to stop.  I want it to stop when 7 integers have been entered

This is for an academic assignment.

Comment: Just replace `number.length` with `7`.  With your implementation, you cannot enter number greater than 10000000 as it will cause `IndexOutOfBounds` exception

Comment: Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50307498/find-max-non-repeatable-value-in-the-array-with-a-time-on/50308191#50308191)